# CSS3 webkit-scrollbar hidden when not needed

Tags: css, webkit

I have the following code to style custom scrollbars, but when the scrollbar is not needed because the content is not very long, I would like to hide the scrollbar. Is this possible?

Here's the code I have so far...

```
.myscroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;     
}

.myscroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color:#D4D4D4;
}

.myscroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 3px;
    background-color:#0085bf ;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the element is having class `myscroll`, you can try following css

```
    .myscroll{
        overflow:auto;
    }
```

It might solve your issue.

Comment: This still shows a blank scrollbar when you hover over the element.

Comment: setting overflow:auto in .myscroll doesn't work for you?